# SQL Server "Index Usage Statistics" report causes "incorrect syntax near ')'"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

In SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition:

```
SELECT @@version
```

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2011 00:54:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

with non-express edition tools:

> ```
> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio    10.50.2500.0 
> Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)   6.1.7601.17514 
> Microsoft MSXML                           3.0 6.0
> Microsoft Internet Explorer               9.0.8112.16421
> Microsoft .NET Framework                  2.0.50727.5448
> Operating System                          6.1.7601
> ```

running on Windows Small Business Server 2011 Standard 64-bit:

[image]

Against a database in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode:

[image]

If I try to run the **Index Usage Statistics** report I get the error:

[image]

How to make it go away?

I threw in every red herring I could think of. There should be enough extraneous information that everyone can throw out a theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various reports in SQL Server Mgmt Studio make use of [DMV (dynamic management views)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx) like the [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx) to fetch their data.

Those DMV are only available if you're running on compatibility level 90 (SQL Server 2005) and up. You won't be able to get this to work if you're stuck in SQL Server 2000 compatibility level (80), unfortunately.

Comment: That did the trick. Hopefully there was nothing i was doing in 2003 that is "bad" in 2005 compatibility mode.